# Solving tricky Knuth Up Arrow Notations

Tags: notation, exponentiation

How would I solve something like
$2\uparrow\uparrow n$? when n ≤1?
Or
$2\uparrow^{-2}2$?

Thanks!

Comment: To be precise, there is nothing to *solve* in $2\uparrow\uparrow n$, it's just an expression with some meaning. (The same way there is nothing to "solve" in the expression $2^3$; you can only *evaluate* it.)

Comment: Up-arrow is related to tetration, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration and http://www.tetration.org/.  There has been work to extend it to non-natural arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible answer:

We know that for every positive integer n, m↑↑n = log<sub>m</sub>[m↑↑(n+1)]. If we assume the same equation to hold for nonpositive n, we get:

m↑↑0 = log<sub>m</sub>(m↑↑1) = log<sub>m</sub>m = 1

m↑↑-1 = log<sub>m</sub>(m↑↑0) = log<sub>m</sub>1 = 0

m↑↑-2 = log<sub>m</sub>(m↑↑-1) = log<sub>m</sub>0 = -infinity (in other words, it is undefined)

This seems to be the only logical extension of the double-arrow operator to nonpositive *integer* "exponents".

As for the extension to a "nonpositive number of arrows", it is even simpler:

m↑<sup>0</sup>n = m*n (ordinary multiplication)

m↑<sup>-1</sup>n = m+n (ordinary addition)

But the next one is somewhat surprising:

m↑<sup>-2</sup>n = (m+n+4)/2 (you might want to try and verify on your own that this is correct, by proving that m+n is indeed equal to this function iterated n times on m)

So the expression in your original question, 2↑<sup>-2</sup>2, evaluates to (2+2+4)/2 = 4. Of-course, this is hardly surprising, since 2[any-number-of-arrows]2 always evaluates to 4.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of an interpretation with a negative number of arrows, so I'll just address the case where $n \geq 1$.

With up arrow notation, you can "strip away" an arrow and then write $n$ copies of 2, each separated by one fewer arrows than you had previously. In your case, we'd have
$$
2 \uparrow \uparrow n = \underbrace{2 \uparrow 2 \uparrow \cdots \uparrow 2}_{n \text{ copies of } 2}.
$$

A single uparrow is just regular exponentiation, so we'll get an exponent tower of 2's having height $n$.

For example, when $n = 3$, this all works out to
$$
\begin{align*}
2 \uparrow \uparrow 3 &= 2 \uparrow 2 \uparrow 2\\
&= (2 \uparrow 2) \uparrow 2\\
&= (2^2) \uparrow 2\\
&= 2^{2^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: But how would I "strip away" an arrow and then write $n$ copies of 2, when $n$ is a negative number? How do you solve $2\uparrow\uparrow{-2}$?

Comment: I don't think the up arrow notation is defined for negative values of $n$, but it's possible I've just never seen it (though I can't imagine a reasonable interpretation for it). If you can find an example of its use online, I'd be interested to see it.